# Constraint-based Type Inference with Algebraic Data

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, functional-programming, inductive-datatypes, typing

I am working on an expression based language of ML genealogy, so it naturally needs type inference >:)

Now, I am trying to extend a constraint-based solution to the problem of inferring types, based on a simple implementation in EOPL (Friedman and Wand), but they elegantly side-step algebraic datatypes.

What I have so far works smoothly; if an expression `e` is `a + b`, `e : Int`, `a : Int` and `b : Int`. If `e` is a match,

```
match n with
  | 0 -> 1
  | n' -> n' * fac(n - 1)`,
```

I can rightly infer that the `t(e) = t(the whole match expression)`, `t(n) = t(0) = t(n')`, `t(match) = t(1) = t(n' * fac(n - 1)` and so on...

But I am very unsure when it comes to algebraic datatypes. Suppose a function like filter:

```
let filter pred list =
  match list with
    | Empty -> Empty
    | Cons(e, ls') when pred e -> Cons (e, filter ls')
    | Cons(_, ls') -> filter
```

For the list type to remain polymorphic, Cons needs to be of type `a * a list -> a list`. So, in establishing these constraints, I obviously need to look up these types of my algebraic constructors - the problem I now have is the 'context-sensitivity' of multiple uses of algebraic constructors - how do I express in my constraint equations that the `a` in each case needs to be the same?

I am having trouble finding a general solution to this, and I am unable to find much literature on this. Whenever I find something similar - expression based language with constraint-based type inference - they stop just short of algebraic datatypes and polymorphism.

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: @Guy I don't mean to sound ungrateful, but I am not looking for an off-the-shelf solution - do you have any suggestions? Most existing docs I could find (like the INRIA papers on ML, OCaml...) are much more extensive than what I need (and am capable of understanding).

Comment: I'd start with the inference chapter in [ATTAPL](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/attapl/), I think they discuss everything you need at an accessible level.

Comment: @Gilles I think ATTAPL is the only 'classic' PL book I don't have on my bookshelf : P But thanks, I will take a look on monday, I sit on a floor at Uni with perhaps 10 copies distributed across the offices : )

Comment: @Kris did you ever find an accessible resource tackling this problem? My implementation of a "mini ML" is stuck on exactly this problem... I think I found the relevant chapter from ATTAPL (http://pauillac.inria.fr/~fpottier/publis/emlti-final.pdf) and skimmed the section on algebraic data types, but I'm afraid it's a bit over my head.

Comment: @spacemanaki Yes, I have since found https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8983/233b3dff2c5b94efb31235f62bddc22dc899.pdf to be an excellent resource for exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Mini ML](http://v2matveev.blogspot.com/2010/05/f-parsing-simple-language.html) Specifically the Type Inference section.

This contains sample code in F# for a complete parser of a simple functional language. More importantly the Type Inference section implements the Hindley-Milner algorithm which is what is found in most type inference system. The author also provides links to two other important documents to help in understanding Hindley-Milner; one being a kind of high level introduction and the other being a paper that describes the implementation of the algorithm in code.

Comment: Single links are generally not an answer. Please elaborate what can be found there and why it helps.